# listing rooms available[hotel reservation]

Tags: sql

In the `not` in query it is still returning the roomname with cancelled status but when I removed the query for trapping of dates the `status !='cancelled'` is working. Is there
something wrong with the query for trapping of dates?

```
$tbl_comp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM roomlist 
WHERE type='$roomtype' and status = '1' 
and name NOT IN(select name from roomreservation where status  !='cancelled'

and 
arrival between '$arrival' and '$departure'
or departure between '$arrival' and '$departure'
or '$arrival'  between arrival and departure
or '$departure' between arrival and departure)");
```

Comment: Can you give us the table structure with sample data and expected output on _www.sqlfiddle.com_, so it would be easier for us to work on?

Comment: It looks like you're doing a double negative. do you want the rooms that aren't cancelled or the ones that are? If you want the ones that aren't, take off the boom (!)

Comment: Also, it's hard to know for sure what you meant, but you might be getting tripped up by AND having a higher precedence than OR. Try surrounding the four BETWEEN conditions with parentheses.

Comment: @Scotch  He seems to be looking for vacant rooms, i.e. rooms with no booking that are both active and overlapping on dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with the query is that `status != 'cancelled'` applies only to the first part of the date test.

Another problem is that `BETWEEN` does an inclusive comparation, while you probably accept new arrivals on the same day as the departure of another booking. The you need to compare the dates using < and > instead of `BETWEEN`. However, the test in the inner query can be simplified to this:

```
SELECT name FROM roomreservation
WHERE status != 'cancelled'    -- if cancelled: no conflict 
AND '$arrival' < departure     -- if $arrival >= departure: no conflict
AND '$departure' > arrival     -- if $departure <= arrival: no conflict
```

Answer (score 0):

its work for me

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    reservation
WHERE
    room = "3" AND
    status = 1 AND
    '2015-12-03' BETWEEN arrival AND departure OR
    '2015-12-06' BETWEEN arrival AND departure
```